# Android map marker smooth movement

Tags: android, android-maps

I'm doing an android application which involves google map to show smooth location movement.for example,if the user is in driving.,the marker which indicates current position should do smooth move according to the user move.How could i do that.I don't have any idea in this.Help is much appreciated.thanks.

Comment: Have you got solution for it?